# Customize mini frames color on beamer

Tags: beamer, color, mini-frames

I fail to customize my mini frame colors and to make appear a separation line and bullets. I would like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Only with my already defined background colors.

How can I do that ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setbeameroption{hide notes}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]



\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone} % don't show bookmarks on initial view
\useoutertheme{miniframes}


\definecolor{foreground}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{background}{RGB}{24,24,24}
\definecolor{title}{RGB}{107,174,214}
\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{155,155,155}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{102,255,204}
\definecolor{hilight}{RGB}{102,255,204}
\definecolor{vhilight}{RGB}{255,111,207}


\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=title}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=subtitle}
\setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=foreground,bg=background}

\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=foreground} % color of bullets
\setbeamercolor{subitem}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate subbody}{fg=gray}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{{\textendash}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subitem}{size=\footnotesize}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\raisebox{5pt}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\hfill\makebox[20pt]{\color{gray}
          \scriptsize\insertframenumber}}}\hspace*{5pt}}

\newcommand{\bi}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ei}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ig}{\includegraphics}
\newcommand{\subt}[1]{{\footnotesize \color{subtitle} {#1}}}


\setbeamercolor{separation line}{fg=white}

%Colors for the mini frames

\setbeamercolor*{mini frame}{fg=white,bg=blue}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}[default][0]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}[default][0]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\mode<beamer>{\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary,fg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}    {\color{gray}\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=background}
```

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\definecolor{foreground}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{background}{RGB}{24,24,24}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=foreground,bg=background}

\setbeamercolor{below lower separation line head}{bg=white}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.5pt]{below lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamercolor*{mini frame}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=background}

\begin{document}

\section{blub}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Sorry I forgot the MWE.